# Convert One column as column header of other columns

Tags: oracle11g, pivot

I'm still trying to wrap my head around Pivot and Unpivot and like to get my desire result, 
but I can't figure out how to get my desire output. So I'm hoping some of you ORACLE/T-SQL gurus can help me out here.

### Objective of my query:

Convert One column as column header of other columns (other columns will be nested multiple column under which is column header)

Here I've give all information about my question, my expected result & what's I've trying

### Table Script:

```
CREATE TABLE LC_PERFORMANCE_O
(PERIOD VARCHAR2(100), LC_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20), LC_VALUE NUMBER)
```

### Insert Script:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into LC_PERFORMANCE
   (PERIOD, LC_NUMBER, LC_VALUE, PERIOD_NO)
 Values
   ('JANUARY10', 69, 5282964.68, '01');
Insert into LC_PERFORMANCE
   (PERIOD, LC_NUMBER, LC_VALUE, PERIOD_NO)
 Values
   ('FEBRUARY10', 57, 4345701.5, '02');
Insert into LC_PERFORMANCE
   (PERIOD, LC_NUMBER, LC_VALUE, PERIOD_NO)
 Values
   ('MARCH10', 63, 2570537.13, '03');
Insert into LC_PERFORMANCE
   (PERIOD, LC_NUMBER, LC_VALUE, PERIOD_NO)
 Values
   ('APRIL10', 51, 2003928.9, '04');
Insert into LC_PERFORMANCE
   (PERIOD, LC_NUMBER, LC_VALUE, PERIOD_NO)
 Values
   ('MAY10', 62, 2729072.07, '05');
Insert into LC_PERFORMANCE
   (PERIOD, LC_NUMBER, LC_VALUE, PERIOD_NO)
 Values
   ('JUNE10', 51, 5455665.58, '06');
Insert into LC_PERFORMANCE
   (PERIOD, LC_NUMBER, LC_VALUE, PERIOD_NO)
 Values
   ('JULY10', 55, 4499081.21, '07');
Insert into LC_PERFORMANCE
   (PERIOD, LC_NUMBER, LC_VALUE, PERIOD_NO)
 Values
   ('AUGUST10', 55, 2493876.83, '08');
Insert into LC_PERFORMANCE
   (PERIOD, LC_NUMBER, LC_VALUE, PERIOD_NO)
 Values
   ('SEPTEMBER10', 68, 3203650.57, '09');
Insert into LC_PERFORMANCE
   (PERIOD, LC_NUMBER, LC_VALUE, PERIOD_NO)
 Values
   ('OCTOBER10', 107, 7795475.07, '10');
COMMIT;
```

### Input: LC_PERFORMANCE Table

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| PERIOD      | LC_NUMBER | LC_VALUE   | PERIOD_NO |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| JANUARY10   | 69        | 5282964.68 | 01        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| FEBRUARY10  | 57        | 4345701.5  | 02        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| MARCH10     | 63        | 2570537.13 | 03        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| APRIL10     | 51        | 2003928.9  | 04        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| MAY10       | 62        | 2729072.07 | 05        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| JUNE10      | 51        | 5455665.58 | 06        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| JULY10      | 55        | 4499081.21 | 07        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| AUGUST10    | 55        | 2493876.83 | 08        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| SEPTEMBER10 | 68        | 3203650.57 | 09        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

### Expected Output: From a DB View

```
+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|   JANUARY10     |  FEBRUARY10    |    MARCH10      |    APRIL10     |     MAY10       |     JUNE10      | Continuous year |
+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 69 | 5282964.68 | 57 | 4345701.5 | 63 | 2570537.13 | 51 | 2003928.9 | 62 | 2729072.07 | 51 | 5455665.58 | ...    | ...    |
+----+------------+----+-----------+----+------------+----+-----------+----+------------+----+------------+--------+--------+
```

### My Query:

```
CLEAR COLUMNS
COLUMN TEMP_IN_STATEMENT NEW_VALUE STR_IN_STATEMENT;

/

SELECT   DISTINCT
         LISTAGG ('''' || PERIOD || ''' AS ' || PERIOD, ',')
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PERIOD_NO)
            AS TEMP_IN_STATEMENT
  FROM   (SELECT   DISTINCT PERIOD, PERIOD_NO FROM IMPORT_LC_PERFORMANCE);

/

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT PERIOD,LC_VALUE FROM IMPORT_LC_PERFORMANCE)
    PIVOT (MAX( LC_VALUE  ) FOR PERIOD IN (&STR_IN_STATEMENT))
    UNION
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT PERIOD,LC_NUMBER FROM IMPORT_LC_PERFORMANCE)
    PIVOT (MAX( LC_NUMBER  ) FOR PERIOD IN (&STR_IN_STATEMENT))
    )T
```

### Result against my query:

```
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| JANUARY10  | FEBRUARY10 | MARCH10    | APRIL10   | MAY10      | JUNE10     | JULY10     | AUGUST10   | SEPTEMBER10 | OCTOBER10  |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 69         | 57         | 63         | 51        | 62         | 51         | 55         | 55         | 68          | 107        |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 5282964.68 | 4345701.5  | 2570537.13 | 2003928.9 | 2729072.07 | 5455665.58 | 4499081.21 | 2493876.83 | 3203650.57  | 7795475.07 |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+
```